# On Ladner's theorem

Tags: complexity-theory

In Ladner's theorem, can we take $\mathsf{NPI}$ problems to be problems in $\mathsf{SUBEXP}\cap\mathsf{NP}$? Is this a proper subset?

Can we extend Ladner's theorem to interpret $\mathsf{SUBEXP/poly}\cap\mathsf{NP/poly}\neq\emptyset$ hold? Does proper extension of Ladner's theorem indicate an analogous proper subset in $\mathsf{SUBEXP/poly}\cap\mathsf{NP/poly}$?

Comment: Have you checked proofs of Ladner's theorem? That's what I would do, but you are the one asking the question, so it makes more sense for you to do it. If after checking the proofs you still don't know the answer, explain what the proofs do show, and what is the gap. At that point the question might become suitable for cstheory.se.

Comment: Please edit your posts when you have update; don't delete and repost.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus It really is not clear from proof here http://oldblog.computationalcomplexity.org/media/ladner.pdf